# Is there a way to connect the data present in Azure IOT hub to IOT Central smart meter application

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

I have published data to the Azure Iot Hub devices from my hardware devices. Now I want to perform some analysis using the IOT Central's application 'Smart Meter Monitoring' the link to the website is this https://apps.azureiotcentral.com/build/energy.To be more concise, I'm trying to consume the data present in the azure iot hub devices using the the IOT Central's application 'Smart Meter Monitoring' so that i can build dashboards on the data that is consumed. I Have browsed many websites and I am not having any progress in trying to connect azure IOT HUB and the 'Smart Meter Monitoring' application of IOT central. I am beginner in this field want to understand how this integration is made any tutorial or blog will be helpful

Comment: Just to check, is it possible for you to connect your devices straight to IoT Central instead? Or do you absolutely need to have your own hub? IoT Central leverages IoT Hub internally for device connection.

Comment: yes @MatthijsvanderVeer we need our own iot hub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this repo https://github.com/IOTD-Americas/iothub-bridge-function in order to re-send all telemetry from IoT Hub to IoT Central using an Azure Function in real time